# How to set the line chart's y-axis min value in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I create a chart,and I want to show some huge numbers,like 5000,4800...
But the y-axis's min value is 0,and the line looks too smooth.
I want the y value range in [3000,6000],so what should I do? Is there some attribute?
And,could I set the y-axis's length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Using below code: -

```
<mx:LineChart id="lineChart"
                      showDataTips="true"
                      dataProvider="{YourDataProvider}"
                      width="100%"
                      height="100%">
            <mx:verticalAxis>
                <mx:LinearAxis id="ca" 
                               title="XMLList attribute"
                               minimum="3000"
                               maximum="6000"/>
            </mx:verticalAxis>

        </mx:LineChart>
```

Hope this will help.....